# SharePoint User Profile Service Application

Tags: user-profile-service

Do we need User Profile service application for managing permissions and groups in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: **no**. The long answer: the UP service app is used for administering:

- User Profiles
- Profile Sync
- Audiences
- MySite Host
- MySite
- Social tags and notes

This [MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662538.aspx) gives a nice overview of the user profile service app.

Comment: You also need it to support Hybrid workloads with Office 365.